# Why mySQL table won't export properly as HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I use bootstrap 3 template and connect to a mysql database, sort the table and export some datas as HTML table in order to display it on bootstrap webpage.

Here is the mySQL look like :
[image]

The following code won't get expected results:

```
<div class="well">              

<?php               

//MySQL Database Connect
include '/includes/dbconnect.php';

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {

    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>NAME:</th><th>EPOCH</th></tr>"; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<tr><td>"; 
        echo $row['ID'];
        echo "</td><td>";   
        echo $row['NAME'];
        echo "</td><td>";    
        echo $row['NEXT_EVENT'];
        echo "</td></tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>";  
}
?>
</div>  <!-- well -->
```

dbconnect.php :

```
<?php

$localhost="xxx.xx.xxx.com";
$username="dboxxxxxxx";
$password="xxxxxx";
$database="dbxxxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($localhost,$username,$password,$database);

//test if connection failed
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("connection failed: "
        . mysqli_connect_error()
        . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ")");
}
?>
```

original page link can be found here : http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/gpio/dyntable.htm

Comment: sorry, this is a typo error, i connect to a mysql database and try to display datas from that table as HTML table.

Comment: Okay, what do you get back, and what do you want to get back.. or are there errors?

Comment: actually, if you click on the page link i put on the end of my post you can see that datas from mysql table are not displayed.

Comment: Laurent, if you fix the errors in your question, it makes the answers look like nonsense. Please dont do that.

Comment: I think your new problems really need you to ask a NEW Question, as they are not related to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a simple typo

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {

    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>NAME:</th><th>EPOCH</th></tr>"; 
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                                      ^^^^^^^^
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

> While testing Add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); `
```

> to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
>   generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

#### Answer for additional info provided in a comment

From your comment below, it appears you are trying to run PHP code from a web page with a `.htm` extension. ***That wont work unless you have configured Apache to do this***

Change the web page file name to have a `.php` extension and then Apache will pass the PHP code to the PHP interpreter for compilation and execution.

Comment: there was a typo error, you are right.  I edited the source code but http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/gpio/dyntable.htm still won't show the datas in the table .

Comment: See my answer again for the additional answer

Comment: Many thanks, i did not know that.  Because i use bootstrap, i need to have all pages reachable from .htm extension.   is it a .htaccess setting to let Apache run php code into html pages ?

Comment: I dont remember any limitation in bootstrap that insists upon the page being a `.htm`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT ID, NAME, NEXT_EVENT  FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC");

$table = '<table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>EPOCH</th>
            </tr>';
if($result ) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $table .= '<tr>
                    <td>'. $row['ID'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $row['NAME'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $row['NEXT_EVENT'] .'</td>
                   </tr>';
    }
} else {
    $table .= '<tr><td colspan="3">No date found</td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Try this, This will help for your requirement.

Comment: renamed page as .php extension ___ http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/gpio/dyntable.php  now i need to solve errors and warnings

Comment: Kinda late to the party Mukesh adding nothing extra to my answer 20 minutes earlier!

Comment: Warning: include(/includes/dbconnect.php)
Please check the file permission for this

Comment: /includes folder and dbconnect.php have all been set with 755 permission, but still have a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your connection to the database is OK (though the given [page lin](http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/bs3/gpio/dyntable.htm)k suggests otherwise).

It seems the table is not exporting properly because `$result` was misspelled as `$results` in the code segment printing the data rows: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)`.

Try the modification below (also refactored for better readability):

```
<div class="well">              

<?php               

  //MySQL Database Connect
  include '/includes/dbconnect.php';

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM webpilot ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT ASC");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)
  {
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>NAME:</th><th>EPOCH</th></tr>"; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$row['ID']</td>";           
      echo "<td>$row['NAME']</td>";                       
      echo "<td>$row['NEXT_EVENT']</td>";                         
      echo "</tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
  }

?>
</div>  <!-- well -->
```

Also, you may want to check that `$results` and `$row` contain the expected data in the expected formats using `print_r($results)` and `print_r($row)`.

Comment: 27 minutes late and adding nothing over answers that have already been given! Not helpful

Comment: @RiggsFolly by the time I was composing my answer, yours wasn't there, and I didn't see it until I posted. Besides, you didn't mention anything about the db connection errors and whether `$result` and `$row` contain the expected data in the first place.

Comment: 27 minute to compose this answer. Wow